# boost::lexical_cast produces undefined reference for static member variable

Tags: c++, boost

I'm experiencing a linking error with [boost::lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast/examples.html) for a static member variable that I don't understand.

Here's a small sample that demonstrates the problem (I know that it is silly, I could just << candy; but this demonstrates the problem I'm seeing in less trivial use of lexical_cast):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
    void print_candy() const
    {
        cout << "candy is: " << boost::lexical_cast<string>(candy) << endl;
    }
private:
    static const unsigned int candy = 0;
};

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Test t;
    t.print_candy();
    return 0;
}
```

This produces the following error when I compile it:

```
$ /opt/gcc-google-4.8/bin/g++ -Wall -I/usr/include --std=c++11 test.cc -o test
/tmp/cc9MV6cQ.o:test.cc:function Test::print_candy() const: error: undefined reference to 'Test::candy'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Clearly candy is defined.  If I remove the lexical cast and just redirect candy to out, the program compiles and links fine.

Some observations:

- Making the member variable public does *not* remove the problem.  That is, I still get the linker error with a public variable.
- Making the member non-static does make the issue go away.
- If I make a local variable that's a copy of the static one and pass that to the lexical_cast, it works fine.

So I'd like to understand:

- Why is a static member variable coming up as undefined for lexical_cast?
- What is the most elegant way to address this?  I'd prefer not to remove static nor create an otherwise necessary local variable.

Comment: `candy` is not defined, you have a declaration with an initializer. Define it outside the class definition - `int const Test::candy;`

Comment: this compiles and links fine on coliru but fails also on my machine locally  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d3773da965b90cb

Comment: @Praetorian: thanks.  I'll move the declarations outside the class in my case.  Out of curiosity: why can the variable be used locally otherwise but not by lexical_cast?  What about lexical_cast triggers the problem?

Comment: @firebush You're passing `candy` to `lexical_cast` by reference, which constitutes [odr-use](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use) of that variable, so a definition is required. Surprisingly, neither gcc-5.1 nor VS2015 produce the same linker error, while clang does - http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a60795a022f562c4 I suspect some sort of optimization at play with the former two.